# Responsive calendar

Tags: responsive-design, calendar

I'm using

```
<table>
<tbody><tr class="header">
<th>Monday</th>
<th>Tuesday</th>
<th>Wednesday</th>
<th>Thursday</th>
<th>Friday</th>
<th>Saturday</th>
<th>Sunday</th>
</tr>
<tr class="header">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr class="info">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3" class="event">Event details</td>
</tr>....
```

to

```
....</table>
```

From a hard-coded calendar. On a mobile device, 7 columns doesn't really work very well.  I would prefer a day a line format.

What's the easiest or most elegant way to achieve this? I can recode, using search and replace, the original table so I have a 7 column grid of divs but this may be a bit 'slippery'. (replace the `</tr>` with `<br/>`? )

Answer (score 0):

Please check out [this](http://www.bluekeyinteractive.com/how-to-create-a-responsive-calendar/) solution.

HTML:

```
<div class="calendar">
    <ul class="weekdays">
    <li>Sunday</li>
    <li>Monday</li>
    <li>Tuesday</li>
    <li>Wednesday</li>
    <li>Thursday</li>
    <li>Friday</li>
    <li>Saturday</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="days">
    <!-- add filler at beginning of month -->
    <li class="out_of_range calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="out_of_range calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"></div>
    </li>            
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Sun,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 1</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Mon,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 2</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Tue,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 3</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Wed,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 4</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Thu,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 5</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Fri,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 6</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Sat,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 7</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Sun,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 8</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Mon,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 9</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Tue,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 10</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Wed,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 11</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Thu,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 12</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Fri,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 13</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Sat,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 14</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Sun,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 15</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Mon,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 16</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Tue,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 17</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Wed,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 18</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Thu,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 19</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Fri,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 20</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Sat,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 21</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Sun,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 22</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Mon,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 23</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Tue,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 24</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Wed,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 25</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Thu,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 26</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Fri,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 27</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Sat,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 28</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Sun,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 29</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Mon,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 30</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"><span class="day">Tue,</span> <span class="month">Mar</span> 31</div>
        <div class="show-info"></div>
    </li>

    <!-- add filler at end of month -->
    <li class="out_of_range calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="out_of_range calendar-day">
        <div class="date day_cell"></div>
    </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="footer-weekdays">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<p>More info at <a href="http://www.bluekeyinteractive.com/how-to-create-a-responsive-calendar/" target="_blank">http://www.bluekeyinteractive.com/how-to-create-a-responsive-calendar/</a>
```

SCSS:

```
@import "compass/css3";

*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@mixin breakpoint($point) {
  @if $point == medium {
    @media (min-width: 1000px) { @content; }
  }
  @else if $point == small {
    @media (min-width: 628px)  { @content; }
  }
}

div.calendar{
    width:100%;
    padding:20px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;


    .weekdays,
    .footer-weekdays{
    display: none;
    }

    ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding:0;
        list-style-image: none;
    }

  li{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    max-height: 80px;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    background-color:#c3eaf6;
    .day,
    .month{
      display: inline;
    }

    .day {
      display: inline;
      @include breakpoint(small) {
    display: none;
      }
    }

    &.out_of_range {
     display: none;
    }
  }

    @include breakpoint(small) {

    .weekdays,
    .footer-weekdays{
    display: block;
    li {
        background-color:#21b0dc;
        height: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        color:#fff;
    }
    }

    .footer-weekdays li{height:20px;}

        ul{
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            clear: both;
            width: 100%;
            li{
                display: block;
                float: left;
                height: auto;
            max-height: 150px;
                width: 14.2857142857%;
                padding: 10px;

                &.out_of_range {
                    display: block;
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

JS:

```
/**
    Equal Heights Plugin
    Equalize the heights of elements. Great for columns or any elements
    that need to be the same size (floats, etc).

    Version 1.01
    Updated 1/30/2014

    Copyright (c) 2008 Rob Glazebrook (cssnewbie.com) 
    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

    Usage: $(object).equalHeights([minHeight], [maxHeight]);

    Example 1: $(".cols").equalHeights(); Sets all columns to the same height.
    Example 2: $(".cols").equalHeights(400); Sets all cols to at least 400px tall.
    Example 3: $(".cols").equalHeights(100,300); Cols are at least 100 but no more
    than 300 pixels tall. Elements with too much content will gain a scrollbar.
**/

   (function($) {
     $.fn.equalHeights = function(minHeight, maxHeight) {
      tallest = (minHeight) ? minHeight : 0;
      this.each(function() {
       if($(this).height() > tallest) {
    tallest = $(this).height();
      }
    });
      if((maxHeight) && tallest > maxHeight) tallest = maxHeight;
      return this.each(function() {
       $(this).height(tallest).css("overflow","auto");
     });
    }
  })(jQuery);

$(".days li").equalHeights(100,150);
```